# Count co-appearance of 2 variables in list of lists

Tags: python, performance, count, lookup, appearance

I have a list of lists containg string values each (~130.000 lists, each list has ~15 items). Lists may contain duplicates but that is by design, they need to stay = I can't use a set here.

I create tuple combinations of each list values(~5.600.000 tuples) and want to count how many times each tuple value alone and together appears in the lists.

So I need to lookup for each tuple values how many times they appear in the lists. So (5.600.000 * (130.000 * 15)) which is .... a lot.

Example:

```
tags: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', '2019'], ['a', 'd', '18', 'gb'], ['aa', 'a', 'dd', 'fb', 'la'], ['aa', 'd', 'ddaa', 'b', 'k', 'l']]
tagSet: {('a', 'aa'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'd'), ('aa', 'b'), ('aa', 'd'), ('a', 'd')}

for tagTuple in tagSet:
    tagA = tagTuple[0]
    tagB = tagTuple[1]
    sumA = sum(tagA in item for item in tags )
    sumB = sum(tagB in item for item in tags )
    sumAB = ??
```

For tuple (a, b) the result should be

```
a: 3, b:2, a+b: 1
```

But how do I count how may times a and b appear together in each list?

**A performant way is needed because of the high number of lists and tuples I need to check.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for how often each of the elements in the lists in `tags` appear, and a `dict` of `Counter` how often each element appears together with each other element.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from itertools import combinations
counts = Counter()
co_counts = defaultdict(Counter)
for lst in tags:
    c = Counter(lst)
    counts.update(c)
    for a, b in combinations(set(lst), 2):
        co_counts[a][b] += min(c[a], c[b])
        co_counts[b][a] += min(c[a], c[b])
```

Creating those is not entirely cheap, either, but much cheaper than what you are currently doing. If your `tags` and `tagSet` have `N` and `M` elements respectively, and the lists in `tags` have on average have `K` elements (`K` being much smaller than `N` or `M`), then this has "only" `N * K²` as opposed to `N * M * K`.

Then, you can just get your values directly from those `Counter` dictionaries.

```
for a, b in tagSet:
    print(a, b, counts[a], counts[b], co_counts[a][b])
```

This gives the following output:

```
a b 3 2 1
a aa 3 3 2
b d 2 2 1
a d 3 2 1
aa d 3 2 1
aa b 3 2 2
```

Comment: Do you know if that approach is faster than "x in list for list in lists" and if yes how much? Running that code for +1 hour now and it could take a few more I guess.

Comment: @Vega I guess that was still N*M, just without the K factor. Please check my update, this should be considerably faster.

Comment: Wow, that is super fast. Took ~5-6 minutes for my whole dataset. Thank you so much! Thought about multicore support but that's fast enough now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the same detection expression you would use in an `if` statement:

```
sumAB = sum(tagA in item and tagB in item for item in tags )
```

Comment: Works but is way too slow for my amount of data sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **and** condition `tagA in item and tagB in item`:

```
tags = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', '2019'], ['a', 'd', '18', 'gb'], ['aa', 'a', 'dd', 'fb', 'la'], ['aa', 'd', 'ddaa', 'b', 'k', 'l']]
#tagSet = {('a', 'aa'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'd'), ('aa', 'b'), ('aa', 'd'), ('a', 'd')}
tagSet = [('a', 'b')]

for tagTuple in tagSet:
    tagA = tagTuple[0]
    tagB = tagTuple[1]
    sumA = sum(tagA in item for item in tags )
    sumB = sum(tagB in item for item in tags )
    sumAB = sum(tagA in item and tagB in item for item in tags)
    print(sumA)
    print(sumB)
    print(sumAB)
```

Comment: Works but is way too slow for my amount of data sadly.